# How to embed a new line in innertext

Tags: c#, asp.net

How will I be able to force a newline(or a line break) in innertext

```
HtmlGenericControl li;
li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
li.InnerText = sdr.GetValue(0).ToString()+"\n"+sdr.GetValue(1).ToString();      
myList.Controls.Add(li);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`<br />`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp) html tag for line break instead of `\n` and use innerHtml instead of innerText

```
li.InnerHtml = sdr.GetValue(0).ToString()+"<br />"+sdr.GetValue(1).ToString();
```

Comment: its not working...instead of getting a newline the <br /> gets printed between the strings

Comment: Use [`InnerHtml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol.innerhtml(v=vs.80).aspx) instead.

Comment: use innerHTML instead of innerText

Comment: InnerHtml is the key

Comment: Is InnerHTML safe? In my experience, if you can get an XSS payload in the back-end, InnerHTML will execute it, whereas InnerText will not. I always prefer InnerText over InnerHTML for this reason.

Comment: This is not what was asked. InnerHtml and innerText totally behave differently

Answer (score 5):

You can use with [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) property also.

> Gets the newline string defined for this environment.

```
li.innerText = sdr.GetValue(0).ToString()+ Environment.NewLine +sdr.GetValue(1).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `li.InnerHtml` property and `<br />` for next line.

```
li.InnerHtml = sdr.GetValue(0).ToString()+"<br />"+sdr.GetValue(1).ToString();
```

Comment: This is not what was requested